# (I don't have this problem on my local host)... SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myworldm_ecommerce'@'cp-9.hkdns.co.za'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having this error on cpanel...

```
$products = products::inRandomOrder()->take(3)->get();
```

Caused by the above line of code.

I've tried to tried editing my .env file and everything there is as it should be..

I even tried to edit the config/database.php file which I didn't have to edit on my local host.

I also tried running this commands
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache and 
php artisan config:cache

Please assist with a different solution

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: On a file system level "Access Denied" is usually an OS related write permission exception. As such your server *itself* is likely being denied write access.

Comment: Well the error says that the user name has not to access of db server.

Comment: Yea I would check the user and pass on the cpanel sql to make sure you have given it permission for the db

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.env` file to be sure that you have the correct database credentials in there. If you do and are still getting the error, clear the the config cache with either `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache` and try it again